# Connotations and use of 日本晴(れ)

Tags: usage, connotation

I know that 日本晴れ （にっぽん・ばれ）(it can be にほん, but is most commonly にっぽん) literally means "sunny Japan" and gives the sense of a clear sky, but I was wondering: are there any other connotations of this? I was wondering since I have seen it a lot recently, like in songs (some of which are quite patriotic, so I am not surprised), but it is also a name of a section of a soccer magazine, or a magazine as a whole, I believe.
Thanks in advance, everyone!　ありがとうございます！

Comment: You know that 日本晴れ literally means "sunny Japan". How do you know this?

Comment: @BJCUAI 晴れ（はれ）means "sunny" or "clear sky", and 日本 means "Japan", so I figured. Also, it is what Google Translate says when I double-checked. However, I was just wondering if it meant something else since it seems to be a reoccurring word basically meaning Japan, or so I think.

Comment: One's understanding should never be based on or confirmed solely through Google Translate, as it is too unreliable and doesn't understand context very well. From what I've read, expressions with 日本＿＿ simply mean 'the ultimate example of _____', similar to saying 'The ______-est under the sun.'.

Comment: @BJCUAI Thank you so much for your suggestion! I did not base my understanding of this on what Google Translate said, but I had already assumed its meaning way before using Google Translate. I have literally heard 日本晴れ by itself without context, much like the soccer magazine. Thanks again for your contribution, it really helped me have another take on this word/phrase.

Comment: I'm glad that my suggestion was useful ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me, 日本晴れ (usually read にほんばれ rather than にっぽんばれ) is nothing more than a catchy recurring phrase heard in lyrics, titles or such. It refers to a beautiful clear sky, but I have never wondered or sought its meaning deeper than that. I was aware of no particular connection between 日本晴れ and soccer prior to [this](https://www.soccer-king.jp/news/japan/national/20191107/995868.html). Of course it's never used in serious meteorological contexts. By the way, if you are curious, [this chiebukuro question](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1412204499) says this phrase is very old.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I knew what it meant but wasn't sure if there was a particular meaning for it or if it had other connotations. Thanks again!